# Isomorphism between rationals and polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

For each of the following statements, prove it if it is true, and if it is false, give an explanation.

**a)** $\mathbb{Q}^*$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ under $+$, where $\mathbb{Q}^*=\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$.

**b)** $\mathbb{Q}^+$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ under $+$, where $\mathbb{Q}^+$ are positive rationals.

**My approach:** For the second part of the problem I have defined explicit mapping $$f:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}^+$$ defined by $f(a_1+a_2x+\dots+a_{n+1}x^n)=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_{n+1}^{a_{n+1}}$ where $p_n$ is $n$-th prime number.

I was able to show that this mapping is bijective homomorphism, i.e. isomorphism.

But I am not able to come up with something with the first part of the problem.

Would be very grateful for help.

**P.S.** More general question: How to solve such type of problems? Is there some technique?

**P.P.S** Also the second part of the problem was proven by constructing explicit isomorphism. Is it possible to prove it without counstructing mapping?

Comment: HINT: $-1$ has finite order in $\mathbb{Q}^*$. Are there elements of finite order in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: It is possible to do Part 2 without an explicit map, but you'd need to do some work: prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a free abelian group of rank $\aleph_0$, and then show that $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is also a free abelian group of rank $\aleph_0$, and conclude that they are isomorphic from that. But showing they are free of that rank will, implicitly construct isomorphisms between them...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, because in lectures we dealing with free abelian groups. And honestly to say I think that these problems can be proven with the theory of free abelian groups. But i did not digest the theory quite well

Comment: yes, they can. You would want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is free on the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$, and that $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is free on the basis $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You've done a great job with the **b** part! In general, constructing an isomorphism is the cleanest way to show it exists. To prove that no isomorphism exists, you can show that one group possesses some property that the other does not.

For the first question, try to find an element in $\mathbb Q^*$ of order 2 ($x\neq 1$ such that $x^2=1$), and show that no element of $\mathbb Z[x]$ under addition has order 2 (i.e. that no non-zero polynomial $p \in\mathbb Z[x]$ satisfies $p+p=0$).